# Not understanding read command in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand what's going on with my `read` function.  I'm simply doing a `readline` of a text document I created in canopy.  For some reason it only gives me `w` for whatever value I put in.  I'm new to the world of Python so I'm sure its an easy answer!  Thanks for your help!

```
import os

my_file = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Python Files/Test Text.txt"),'r')

print my_file.readline(3)

my_file.close()
```

My Text document is below

```
w
o
r
d
s
```

Comment: Did you know that there are python documents so you don't have to guess what the arguments mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`my_file.readline(3)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) reads *up to* 3 bytes from the first line.
The first line contains a `w` and an end-of-line character.

If you want to read up to the *first 3 bytes* regardless of the line, use `my_file.read(3)`. Note that end-of-line characters are included in the count.

If you want to print the *first 3 lines*, you could use

```
import os
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Python Files/Test Text.txt"),'r') as my_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(my_file):
        if i >= 3: break
        print(line)
```

or

```
import itertools as IT
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Python Files/Test Text.txt"),'r') as my_file:
    for line in IT.islice(my_file, 3):
        print(line)
```

For short files you could instead use

```
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Python Files/Test Text.txt"),'r') as my_file:
    lines = my_file.readlines()
    for line in lines[:3]:
        print(line)
```

but note that `my_file.readlines()` returns a list of *all* the lines in the
file.  Since this can be very memory-intensive if the file is huge, and since it
is usually possible to process a file line-by-line (which is much less
memory-intensive), generally the first two methods of reading a file are
preferred over the third.

Answer (score 1):

> > > 'readline([size]) -> next line from the file, as a string.Retain newline.  A non-negative size argument limits the maximum number of bytes to return (an incomplete line may be returned then).Return an empty string at EOF.

`readline` reads next line and so on.The argument `size` is for how many bytes should it read from the corresponding line.

Comment: Newer [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html?highlight=readline#io.IOBase.readline) now calls the `size` argument `limit` which I think clarifies much. This is a good answer derived from unclear docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`f.readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) does not give random access to the file.  I think you want to read the third (or maybe fourth if you're zero-indexing) line.  The argument that you're passing to [`f.readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) is a maximum byte count to read, rather than a specific line to read.